# how to solve File upload validation problem in yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to upload a file in yii2, the same code was working fine before but for some reason i can't figure out it stopped working after a lot of checks i notice the validate method of upload model is returning false and in the error message it says `Array ( [file] => Array ( [0] => Only files with these extensions are allowed: png, jpg,jpeg,gif,pdf. ) )` but the most weird thing is i uploaded a jpg file i also try to upload a png file the same error, when i remove the check for extension in the model rules it works fineor totally remove the validation is also work, i don't know what am missing here any help would be appreciated.

```
NOTE  //with the validation or the extension check for extension in place the codes in the if() 
statement fails to execute but rather the else statement execute, removing the validation or the 
extension check the code in if() works fine   

  class Upload extends Model 
{

public $file;
public $randomCharacter;
public $fileDirectory;

public function rules()
   {
        
        return[
         
                  [['file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false,'maxSize'=>1024 * 1024 * 2, 'extensions'=> ['png, jpg,jpeg,gif,pdf']],
              ];
   }
   

 public function upload($uploadPath=NULL)
   {
      if(isset($uploadPath) && $uploadPath !==NULL){
          $filePath = $uploadPath;
      }else{
          $filePath = "@frontend/web/uploads/";
      }
        //generate random filename
        $rand = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(10). '_' . time();
        
        //assign generated file name to randomCharacter property
        $this->randomCharacter = $rand;

        //define the upload path;
          if ($this->validate()){
                $path = \Yii::getAlias($filePath);
                $this->fileDirectory = $this->randomCharacter .'.'.$this->file->extension;
                echo $path.$this->fileDirectory;
                exit;
                $this->file->saveAs($path.$this->fileDirectory );
               
                return true;
        }else{
           // return false;
            //with validation in place the else statement in executed
            print_r($this->getErrors());
            exit;
        }
       
    }
    
 
    
}
```

Comment: Did you tried without [ ] ?
`'extensions'=> 'png, jpg, jpeg, gif, pdf'`

Comment: Exactly - it should be either an array of strings with extensions or just one string with extensions list separated with comma, and/or space.

Comment: @Juan.Queiroz   that works thanks a lot u guys have my day, add it as answer i will accept it

Comment: What helped me was setting `'checkExtensionByMimeType' => false` for the validator: `[['file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'checkExtensionByMimeType' => false,'maxSize'=>1024 * 1024 * 2, 'extensions'=> ['png, jpg,jpeg,gif,pdf']]` ... might help someone in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the straight brackets of attribute "extensions"

**Instead of:**

`[['file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false,'maxSize'=>1024 * 1024 * 2, 'extensions'=> ['png, jpg,jpeg,gif,pdf']],`

**You should have this:**

`[['file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false,'maxSize'=>1024 * 1024 * 2, 'extensions'=> 'png, jpg, jpeg, gif, pdf'],`